# Have I thought of everything in this wrapper around boost::thread_group?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety

`boost::thread_group` doesn't automatically clean up contained threads when they end, so I needed something like that described in [this `boost-users` list post](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/thread-group-removal-of-items-tp2585545p2585546.html). However, in my opinion that code is *not* safe, because there's no guarantee that `tp` will be `.reset` before the thread reaches its `th_ptr.get()` call.

After an initial attempt at re-inventing `boost::thread_group` entirely ([which failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434762/why-might-this-thread-management-pattern-result-in-a-deadlock)), I came up with this wrapper and, after much sweat, I believe it's complete and correct. It seems to fix every deadlock that was generally reproducible during its development, so I think I've got them all.

Of course, I'm not sure.

What do you think of my wrapper?

<sup>(It *also* performs some signalling sanity — I only want signals to be handled in the "root"/parent thread, otherwise all hell breaks loose.)</sup>

#### has-threads.h

```
#ifndef HASTHREADS_H
#define HASTHREADS_H

#include <set>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

/**
 * Concept to be derived by any class that should be capable of launching and tracking
 * worker threads, and waiting for workers to complete at object destruction.
 * 
 * Non-copyable.
 * 
 * 
 * ** NOTE REGARDING DESTRUCTION **
 * 
 * Threads are automatically waited for on destruction, but they are not interrupted. So:
 *  - Deriving classes should call interruptThreads() if any are persistent and would not terminate
 *    soon on their own.
 *  - They should also call waitForThreads() if any callback uses member data, to ensure that
 *    the thread finished execution before the member data is destroyed.
 * 
 * 
 * ** ANOTHER NOTE **
 * 
 * Be careful not to expose boost::thread_group::size(); if a thread uses it, this could cause
 * a deadlock with boost::thread_group::join_all(). Instead, we can track it ourselves, safely.
 */
struct has_threads
{
    public:

        /**
         * Asks all pending threads to terminate.
         * 
         * See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html
         * for what this actually means.
         */
        void interruptThreads();

        /**
         * Wait for all pending threads to terminate.
         */
        void waitForThreads();

    protected:
        has_threads();
        ~has_threads();

        /**
         * Create and run a tracked thread.
         */
        template <typename Callable>
        void createThread(Callable f, bool allowSignals = false);

        /**
         * Blocks SIGINT, SIGTERM and SIGQUIT signals in the current thread.
         * Should always be used in a new thread, since we have a dedicated
         * signal handling thread that we want to always receive any of these
         * signals.
         */
        static void blockSignalsInThisThread();

        /**
         * Returns the number of threads currently managed by this object.
         */
        size_t threadCount() const;

    private:

        has_threads(has_threads const&);

        /**
         * Entrypoint function for a thread.
         * Wraps the user-provided worker function in signal and exception handling.
         */
        template <typename Callable>
        void runThread(Callable f, bool allowSignals, boost::thread* tp);


        boost::thread_group* grp;
        size_t count;

        mutable boost::mutex thread_create_lock;
        mutable boost::mutex thread_start_lock;
        mutable boost::mutex thread_removal_lock;
        mutable boost::mutex count_lock;
};


template <typename Callable>
void has_threads::createThread(Callable f, bool allowSignals)
{
    {
        // Although boost::thread_group does a good job of looking after threads for us,
        // it doesn't auto-remove objects wrapping terminated threads. So we must do that... carefully.

        thread_start_lock.lock(); // thread creation starts
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock l(thread_create_lock);

        // We need `tp` to be valid *before* the thread starts, so that its third argument is
        // always guaranteed to be valid. But we also need `tp` to be the pointer we put into the
        // thread_group. So we swap a running thread object into the original non-running one.
        boost::thread* tp = new boost::thread;

        boost::thread tmp(&has_threads::runThread<Callable>, this, f, allowSignals, tp);
        tp->swap(tmp);
        grp->add_thread(tp);

        {
            boost::mutex::scoped_lock l(count_lock);
            count++;
        }
    }
}


template <typename Callable>
void has_threads::runThread(Callable f, bool allowSignals, boost::thread* tp)
{
    if (!allowSignals)
        blockSignalsInThisThread();

    {
        // Wait until createThread's work with this thread object is definitely done
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock l(thread_create_lock);
    }

    thread_start_lock.unlock(); // thread creation is now deemed to be utterly complete

    try {
        f();
    }
    catch (boost::thread_interrupted& e) {

        // Yes, we should catch this exception! Letting it bubble over is _potentially_ dangerous:
        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6375121

        std::cout << "Thread " << boost::this_thread::get_id() << " interrupted (and ended)." << std::endl;
    }
    catch (std::exception& e) {
        std::cout << "Exception caught from thread " << boost::this_thread::get_id() << ": " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    catch (...) {
        std::cout << "Unknown exception caught from thread " << boost::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
    }

    // If the group is in the middle of a boost::thread_group::join_all, then boost::thread_group::remove_thread
    // would block as they sit on the same mutex. Silly >.< So we check a "removal" flag first.
    {
        boost::mutex::scoped_try_lock l(thread_removal_lock);
        if (!l) // can only occur when has_threads::waitForThreads() is in progress and we shouldn't be self-deleting
            return;

        grp->remove_thread(tp);
        {
            boost::mutex::scoped_lock l(count_lock);
            count--;
        }

        delete tp;
    }
}


#endif
```

#### has-threads.cpp

```
#include "has-threads.h"
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <csignal>

#include <iostream>

has_threads::has_threads()
    : grp(NULL), count(0)
{
    grp = new boost::thread_group();
}

has_threads::~has_threads()
{
    waitForThreads();
    delete grp;
}

void has_threads::interruptThreads()
{
    grp->interrupt_all();
}

void has_threads::waitForThreads()
{
    // Let any thread initialisation finish, otherwise
    // we might see deadlock on `thread_create_lock`.
    thread_start_lock.lock();
    thread_start_lock.unlock();

    {
        // Protects from threads being created whilst we join everything we already have.
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock l1(thread_create_lock);

        // Protects from threads in the process of destroying themselves
        // from conflicting with the following logic.
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock l2(thread_removal_lock);

        grp->join_all();

        // Now reset the group, so that any thread objects whose threads ended
        // during that `join_all` are destroyed properly.
        delete grp;
        grp = new boost::thread_group();
    }
}

size_t has_threads::threadCount() const
{
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock l(count_lock);
    return count;
}

void has_threads::blockSignalsInThisThread()
{
    sigset_t signal_set;
    sigemptyset(&signal_set);
    sigaddset(&signal_set, SIGINT);
    sigaddset(&signal_set, SIGTERM);
    sigaddset(&signal_set, SIGHUP);
    sigaddset(&signal_set, SIGPIPE); // http://www.unixguide.net/network/socketfaq/2.19.shtml
    pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &signal_set, NULL);
}
```

Comment: **Note:** Yes, I'm aware that thread pools are "better" in a lot of cases. But I do want to be able to just create and destroy threads at will.

Comment: And, yes, all this locking makes me think "gosh, there _must_ be a simpler way", but I don't think that there is. Perhaps you can point out something I've missed.

Answer (score 6):

I think you have **UB** here: `mutex::unlock()` must only be called (1) if the `mutex` is presently locked and (2) by the same thread that `lock()`ed it in the first place (i.e. *if the calling thread owns the mutex*). Anything else is UB (at least for `std::mutex`, but I suspect also for `boost::mutex`).

Your code is sufficiently complex for me not to be sure whether you have this type of UB.

However, if you avoid explicit calls to `mutex::lock()` and `mutex::unlock()` but instead use RAII via `lock_guard<>`, `unique_lock<>`, or `shared_lock<>`, you should be on the safe side.

Comment: You're right - I _deliberately_ do the locking in one thread and the locking in another. I had no idea it was undefined but on checking now you're quite right.